# Was Wentworth Woodhouse, Yorkshire, the largest private house in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, architecture

[Wentworth Woodhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wentworth_Woodhouse) is a large country house in South Yorkshire, England.

In 2016, [Mansions Global](https://www.mansionglobal.com/articles/uk-s-largest-private-home-sells-for-7-million-19584) describe it as:

> the largest private house in the UK

In 2014, [Yorkshire Life](https://www.greatbritishlife.co.uk/things-to-do/whats-on/wentworth-woodhouse-the-largest-privately-owned-house-in-europe-6381276) described it as

> the largest privately-owned house in Europe

[Visiting Wentworth Woodhouse: The Grand Home of the Earls Fitzwilliam in Yorkshire](https://independenttravelcats.com/visiting-wentworth-woodhouse-tours-the-largest-private-house-in-england/#Interesting-Facts-about-Wentworth-Woodhouse), dated October 17, 2021 says:

> Wentworth Woodhouse is one of the finest Georgian buildings in the United Kingdom and it has the longest façade of any country home in Europe;..

and

> Wentworth Woodhouse was the largest private home in England until it was sold in 2017 to the Wentworth Woodhouse Preservation Trust who have been breathing new life into the old house and giving it a new future.

Some of the other very large houses and former houses in the UK include:

- [Blenheim Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blenheim_Palace#The_palace_today), still the residence of the Duke of Marlboro.
- [Stowe House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stowe_House), which has been a school since 1923.
- [Knole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knole) Owned by the National Trust, but descendants of the owners still live in part of it.
- [Castle Howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Howard), still a private home.
- [Knowsley Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowsley_Hall), which was half demolished in the 1950s.  Still owned, but not lived in, by descendants of its owners.
- [Prior Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_Park), Bath, now a school.
- [Ashridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashridge), now a business school.
- [Hamillton Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton_Palace), former home of the Dukes of Hamilton, demolished 1921–1926.
- [Eaton Hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaton_Hall,_Cheshire), home of the Dukes of Westminster, mostly demolished in 1961. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eaton_Hall,_Cheshire
- [Eastbury Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastbury_Park), demolished 1782.
- [Audley End House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audley_End_House), mostly demolished in the 18th century.

And there might be other candidates I haven't listed.

Is/was Wentworth Woodhouse the largest current or former private single family house in the UK?

Comment: Your Wikipedia link says it is *two* houses: "Wentworth Woodhouse comprises two joined houses, forming west and east fronts."

Comment: This might get into semantic arguments over what defines a "private house" or "private home".  As well as how "largest" should be measured.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yes, in which case we should use the definitions we think the claimants used. (Perhaps explaining that they might be correct using their definitions, but not the definitions the reader might expect, if that is indeed the case here.)

Comment: Does 'private house' or 'privately-owned house' even imply that it is something like a single residential building? Otherwise factories, apartment blocks or other similar things would qualify as long as they are owned by an individual. I would interpret the wording so that this would fall within the definition but the sources seem to restrict to one-household residences.

Comment: I happened to find a similar question on another site:  https://www.quora.com/Was-Wentworth-Woodhouse-Yorkshire-the-largest-private-house-in-the-UK/answer/Mark-Golding-10?prompt_topic_bio=1  in case it is answered there.

Comment: @quarague Personally, I wouldn't use "house" for any of those things, unless they had _previously_ been a single residence, and even then I would probably expect it to be qualified as "former house" etc; so _that_ part of the definition seems pretty clear to me. I'm less sure on the "private" / "privately-owned" part, though.

Comment: @Weather Vane  The two parts of Wentworth Woodhouse were built at different times but are connected and have doorways between them.  That makes them a single building which was used for a single purpose.   I lived in an old stone farmhouse which had a wooden 2 story addition and a little attached greenhouse added to it at various times.  It was one house, and Wentworth Woodhouse was also one house on a vastly larger scale.

Comment: @IMAoP Each of the buldings listed was built as private mansion and was a private single family residence for decades or centuries before being convered to other uses or demolished.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I was responding to the claim that "factories, apartment blocks or other similar things would qualify as long as they are owned by an individual". No factory would qualify as a private house _while in use as a factory_, because the category "house" does not include factories. That same building might _previously_ have been a private house, but that's an entirely different question. Logically, though, if they had already been converted by 2014, they would not be relevant (since the claim is not "largest which has ever existed").

Comment: Definition of private house will necessarily be a bit fuzzy, because these buildings were often built to house a family plus their servants, but would also have space for several guests. More recently, occupants without huge numbers of servants and lavish lifestyles will probably only live in a small part of the property, while the rest may be used for tourism or other purposes. Hence, you're really left with questions like: for what purpose was it built? how has it been classified historically and presently? how does it compare with other properties?

Comment: This is basically a palace - much of the floorspace is given to ceremonial rooms, the occupants would (apart from the family) also include a small army of servants. Therefore i'd say that any other palace is also fair game? e.g. Versailles with 60.000m²+ of floorspace against wentworth with23.000m² ... Buckingham: 77.000m²